# QTextCursor doesn't return current position

Tags: python, pyqt, python-3.10, pyqt6, qtextcursor

I am working on an app with a text editor based on `QTextEdit`.
I try to achieve a behavior which is similar to Word:
When you move the text cursor to any position in the text the `QTextCharFormat` of the `QTextCursor` is changed to the CharFormat of the character right before the cursor, and the Buttons for Bold/Italic/Underlined, the `QFontComboBox` and the `QComboBox` for the point size of the editor-widget are checked and set accrodingly.

Originally I connected the signal `cursorPositionChanged()` to the method `lastCharFormat` which handles the character format of the character before the cursor by calling `charFormat()`. But this signal turned out to be unsuitable because it emits every time I type in a character. So I used `keyPressEvent()` to catch inputs of the arrow keys and emit a custom signal.

I haven't implemented the text cursor position change by mouse because I noticed a problem with the text cursor position when moving the cursor with the arrow keys. When I move the cursor from the end of the document to the start the cursor return 1 but when I move the cursor one position to the right it returns 0.

**Edit:** Found out that `position()` does not return the current position but the position before.

This is a problem because I assumed the start position of the text editor to be 1 and I had to implement a check because returning the properties of the `QTextCharFormat` at the start position crashes the app and also if there's no text. Apparently this is due to getting stuck in a loop. Anyway the main problem is the strange behavior of the text cursor position.

Why does `QTextCursor` behaves this way? Is it a bug? And how can I get the properties of `QTextCharFormat` of the character right before the text cursor when the user moves the cursor with the arrow keys or the mouse without crashing the app?

Here is part of the code of the custom text editor element that inherits from `QTextEdit`.

```
class TextElement(QTextEdit):
    cursorMoved = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.editor = parent.editor
        self.connectSignals()

    def connectSignals(self) -> None:
        self.cursorMoved.connect(self.lastCharFormat)

    def keyPressEvent(self, e: QKeyEvent) -> None:        
        # Cursor Changed by Key
        if e.key() == Qt.Key.Key_Up or e.key() == Qt.Key.Key_Left or e.key() == Qt.Key.Key_Down or    e.key() == Qt.Key.Key_Right:
            self.cursorMoved.emit()

        return super().keyPressEvent(e)

    def lastCharFormat(self) -> None:
        cursor = self.textCursor()
        # Printing text cursor position to test behavior
        print(cursor.position())
        if cursor.position() > 1:
            tformat = cursor.charFormat()

            # From this point the app crashes if position is the start position (0 or 1)
            family = tformat.fontFamily()
            size = tformat.fontPointSize()
            if tformat.fontWeight() == 700:
                bold = True
            else:
                bold = False
            italic = tformat.fontItalic()
            underlined = tformat.fontUnderline()
            print(f"Char format before cursor: FontFamily: {family}, Size: {size}, Bold: {bold}, Italic: {italic}, Underlined: {underlined}")

            # This function sets the buttons, QFontComboBox and QComboBox with the point sizes of the editor accordingly
            self.editor.setFontProps(family, size, bold, italic, underlined)
```

I tried to set the text cursor position in the keyPressEvent but this didn't correct the text cursor behavior.

Comment: You should always assume that indexes are always 0-based in anything related to programming (and computing in general). There are rare exceptions where counting starts from 1, and they usually are because they're intended for the *user* perspective (which is normally used to start counting from 1), like, for instance, spreadsheets. That said, there's absolutely nothing wrong with using `cursorPositionChanged` (as long as the connected function is properly implemented), but why don't you just use the [`currentCharFormatChanged`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#currentCharFormatChanged) signal?

Comment: I assumed this originally but then I got this strange behavior when moving the cursor with the arrow keys as I've already described. So this remains a problem when checking the character format of the character before the cursor.

Comment: It's impossible to tell you *exactly* what was wrong in your code, as you didn't provide a valid [mre] (for instance, what does `setFontProps()` do?). Also, you're emitting the signal *before* moving the cursor, which is clearly an issue, as you'll always get an inconsistent format, since it would be relative to the *previous* position. In any case, `currentCharFormatChanged` always returns the format at the left of the cursor. Also note that QTextEdit already has functions for the current format (`fontWeight()`, `fontUnderline()` etc.) so you don't really need to query the QTextCursor.

Answer (score 0):

QTextCursor's position is a 0-based index, meaning the first position is 0, not 1. In your code, when you check if the position is greater than 1, you are checking if it's the second position or later. This causes the code to crash when the cursor is at position 0, because you are trying to access the character format of a non-existing character.

To fix the issue, you should change the condition in the lastCharFormat method to check if the position is greater than or equal to 0 instead of greater than 1. This will allow the code to access the character format of the character right before the cursor even when the cursor is at the start position.

```
def lastCharFormat(self) -> None:
cursor = self.textCursor()
print(cursor.position())
if cursor.position() >= 0:
    tformat = cursor.charFormat()
    ...
```

Also, in the keyPressEvent method, you are checking for arrow key presses to emit the cursorMoved signal. This is a good approach, but you should also consider emitting the signal for other types of cursor movement, such as clicking the mouse to move the cursor or using the mouse wheel to scroll. You can do this by connecting to the cursorPositionChanged signal and emitting the cursorMoved signal in the slot connected to cursorPositionChanged.

```
class TextElement(QTextEdit):
cursorMoved = pyqtSignal()

def __init__(self, parent=None) -> None:
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.editor = parent.editor
    self.connectSignals()

def connectSignals(self) -> None:
    self.cursorPositionChanged.connect(self.onCursorPositionChanged)

def onCursorPositionChanged(self):
    self.cursorMoved.emit()

def keyPressEvent(self, e: QKeyEvent) -> None:
    return super().keyPressEvent(e)

def lastCharFormat(self) -> None:
    cursor = self.textCursor()
    if cursor.position() >= 0:
        tformat = cursor.charFormat()
        ...
```

This way, the lastCharFormat method will be called whenever the cursor position changes, whether it's due to a key press, mouse click, or mouse wheel scroll.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Originally I checked for position > 0 but when I checked the positions with the arrow keys the returned position before the first character was 1 to my surprise. When I moved the position 1 to the write ```position()``` returned 0. I have already discovered other strange behavior like this as well when I change the lines with the up and down arrow keys.  So this strange behavior remains a problem when checking the character format.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to musicamante and user1928747 I found the problem.

First I didn't realize that I get the cursor position before the key inputs are passed to the `QTextCursor`. So I used the native signal `cursorPositionChanged` again and it now works without any crashes because I get the current text format properties from the `QTextEdit` itself. I didn't know that both getters of `QTextEdit` and `QTextCursor` had basically the same function.

I edited the code so the text editor doesn't lose the focus when the user sets the text character format with the buttons from the editor.

The `lastCharFormat` function is a little bit messy but it was difficult to handle the text character format at index 0.

Here is the complete edited code of the "TextElement" widget:

```
class TextElement(QTextEdit, BaseElement):
    cursorMoved = pyqtSignal()
    focussed = pyqtSignal(QTextEdit)

    def __init__(self, row, parent=None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.editor = parent.editor
        self.block = parent
        self.row = row
        self.lastChar: str
        self.lastFormat: dict

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.defaultCursor()
        self.typeLang = get("General", "Language")
        self.connectSignals()

    def connectSignals(self) -> None:
        self.cursorPositionChanged.connect(self.onCursorPositionChanged)
        self.cursorMoved.connect(self.lastCharFormat)

        self.editor.colormenu.colorChanged.connect(self.setTColor)
        self.editor.fontChanged.connect(self.setTFont)

    # Initial cursor settings
    def defaultCursor(self) -> None:
        self.lastFormat = self.editor.getFontProps()
        self.setTextColor(QColor().fromString("#000000"))

    # Gets signal from the editor when the font properties are changed by the user
    @pyqtSlot(dict)
    def setTFont(self, props: dict) -> None:
        if self.row.focussedElement == self:
            self.setFocus()
            self.lastFormat = props
            charformat = QTextCharFormat()
            charformat.setFontFamily(props["FontFamily"].family())
            charformat.setFontPointSize(props["FontSize"])
            if props["Bold"]:
                charformat.setFontWeight(QFont.Weight.Bold)
            charformat.setFontItalic(props["Italic"])
            charformat.setFontUnderline(props["Underlined"])
            self.setCurrentCharFormat(charformat)
            self.setTextColor(props["Color"])

    def mousePressEvent(self, e: QMouseEvent) -> None:
        # Because there can be multiple QTextEdits this signal tells the parent which one is used
        self.focussed.emit(self)
        return super().mousePressEvent(e)

    # Created another function for future purposes
    def onCursorPositionChanged(self):
        self.cursorMoved.emit()

    def lastCharFormat(self) -> None:
        cursor = self.textCursor()
        print(cursor.position())
        if self.fontWeight() == 700: 
            bold = True
        else:
            bold = False
        italic = self.fontItalic()
        underlined = self.fontUnderline()
        family = self.hasFormat(self.fontFamily(), self.lastFormat["FontFamily"].family())
        if self.fontPointSize() > 0:
            if self.fontPointSize() % 1 == 0:
                size = int(self.fontPointSize())
            else:
                size = self.fontPointSize()
        else:
            if self.fontPointSize() % 1 == 0:
                size = int(self.lastFormat["FontSize"])
            else:
                size = self.lastFormat["FontSize"]
        
        print("Text color: ", self.textColor().name())
        print(f"Char format before cursor: FontFamily: {family}, Size: {size}, Bold: {bold}, Italic: {italic}, Underlined: {underlined} Color: {self.textColor()}")
        self.editor.setFontProps(family, str(size), bold, italic, underlined, self.textColor())

    def hasFormat(self, fmt, default):
        if fmt:
            return fmt
        else: 
            return default
```

Comment: For future reference, always remember to provide a *valid* [mre] in your questions (as already said, you're using custom functions we know nothing about) and follow a similar principle also when providing answers (even if they are for your own questions), as even this code is missing many aspects that nobody knows anything about you, which makes the answer quite obscure to anybody that may be looking for a solution to a similar problem. Remember, while answers are originally intended for those who ask them, both questions and answer should be useful *for anybody*.